# Customize "New" tab in Word backstage to add custom templates

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I want customize Word's backstage to add custom templates in "New" tab and not another.
Templates come from a web service. I use Office 2010. Application is develop in C# with Visual Studio 2010.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can add custom templates to the *New* tab of Word's backstage view by providing an XML manifest, which describes the template and the location of a preview image.

The detailed steps are described here:

> **[Deploy custom templates in the 2007 Office system](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178976%28office.12%29.aspx)**

Be aware though that this is a rarely used feature and therefore is rather poorly supported. For example, I found the following shortcomings:

- When opening the folder with the custom templates the first time, the view is empty. The second time you access the backstage view, the templates are shown.
- Preview and thumbnail images are cached locally. However, I never found a way to update the local cache (the location of the cache is `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\Spotlight\14`, replace 14 with whatever your Office version is). When manually deleting the cache, you will also have to delete the following Registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Spotlight\Content\<provider name>` (replace 14 with whatever your Office version is).

Comment: Thanks excellent info. Did you delete the cache+registry as a work around to updating the thumbnails? Also I wonder where the cache is located for the user templates. Because in that case there is no "Spotlight" folder. Any idea?

Comment: @Cilvic: I haven't checked this, but as the mechanism looks like being invented for downloading templates using http, it might be that the _Temporary Internet Files_ folder might be used as the cache?

Answer (score 0):

See [Word 2013: Templates location and File/New](http://blogs.msmvps.com/wordmeister/2013/02/06/word-2013-templates-location-and-filenew/).

The Backstage UI extensibility model doesn't provide anything for templates. You need to place your custom template into presonal temaplates folder and then a user will be able to see them.

Also, as a workaround, you may add a custom tab on the Backstage with your own templates (controls) that come from a web service. You can read more about the Backstage UI in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691833(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Customizing the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee815851(v=office.14).aspx)